# Validación con isset de un checkbox no esta funcionando en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, ajax

El siguiente codigo es de una modal para borrar un registro:

```
<form id="frmEliminarPaciente" method="POST">
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEliminarPaciente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEliminarPaciente" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <input type="hidden" name="idPacienteEliminar" id="idPacienteEliminar" value="">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Eliminar Paciente</h5>
        <span type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="eliminarPaciente" name="eliminarPaciente" value="eliminarSi" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="eliminarPaciente">¿Seguro que deseas eliminar al paciente?</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <span class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</span> <!--se pone span por el onSubmit, si se da clic en cerrar tambien se guardaria el paciente-->
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Eliminar Paciente</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El envía por POST el checkbox hacia el jQuery:

```
$('#frmEliminarPaciente').on('submit', eliminarPaciente);
function eliminarPaciente(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#frmEliminarPaciente').serialize(),
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/eliminarPaciente.php",
        success: function(respuesta){
            respuesta = respuesta.trim();
            if(respuesta == 1){
                $('#tablaPacientesLoad').load("pacientes/tablaPacientes.php");
                $("#frmEliminarPaciente")[0].reset();
                swal.fire("¡Listo!", "Paciente eliminado con éxito", "success");
            }else{
                swal.fire(":(", "Error al eliminar al paciente: "+respuesta, "error");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Añado el código jQuery utilizado para obtener el `idPacienteEliminar`:

```
function obtenerIDPacienteEliminar(idPacienteEliminar){ 
    $('#idPacienteEliminar').val('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "idPacienteEliminar="+idPacienteEliminar,
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/eliminarPaciente.php",
        success:function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
            $('#idPacienteEliminar').val(idPacienteEliminar); //le asigno el valor a idPaciente
        }
    });
}
```

El código para obtener el `idPacienteEliminar` si esta haciendo correctamente su trabajo y enviándolo sin problema, excepto cuando en el PHP agrego la validación de que no inserte el registro en la base de datos cuando se presione el botón que abre la modal, si no cuando una vez en la modal se selecciona el checkbox y se da en Guardar, dicho código de PHP es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
    include "../../clases/Usuarios.php";
    $Usuarios = new Usuarios();

    if(isset($_POST['eliminarPaciente'])){ 
        $idPacienteEliminar= (isset($_POST['idPaciente'])) ? $_POST['idPacienteEliminar'] : '';
        if($idPacienteEliminar!=''){
            echo $Usuarios -> eliminarPaciente($idPacienteEliminar);
        }else{
            echo 'No hay paciente';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'No funciona el selector';
    }     
?>
```

Si quito la validación del:

```
if(isset($_POST['eliminarPaciente']))
```

Si se inserta correcto en el ID correcto, sin embargo con la validación "activada" arroja el mensaje del sweet alert del código:

```
echo 'No hay paciente';
```

Imprimiendo el valor de `idPacienteEliminar` mediante `var_dump()` me arroja **string(0) ""** cuando dicho `var_dump()` lo pongo *dentro de la validación del checkbox*, *si lo pongo fuera me regresa correctamente el `idPacienteEliminar` necesario*, tengo unas funciones similares(prácticamente las copie y pegue para hacer estas nuevas) las cuales funcionan sin ningún problema, son las mismas validaciones, la única diferencia son los nombres de los checkbox y abren diferente modal.

El SweetAlert que me arroja es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al presionar el botón que abre la modal en la consola arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito: Se modificaron los valores no únicos del html de la modal por lo cual en la consola no aparece ya el error de id duplicados.

Comment: Depura tu código poniendo en PHP un `var_dump($_POST);` así verás todo lo que hay en el POST y encontrar el error. Cualquier cosa comparte en la pregunta lo que esto arroje. Por otro lado el mensaje de la captura que muestras te está indicando que tienes dos elementos con id no único, lo cual puede ser problemático a la hora de interactuar con Javascript, los id de los elementos deben ser siempre únicos.

Comment: Listo, ya modifique el tema de los is de los elementos, muchas gracias por el comentario! Ahora, con PHP, creo que no explique muy bien en la pregunta, ya la modifiqué.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para mostrar la ventana modal y asignar el valor al campo `idPaciente`.

Comment: Listo, ya hice las modificaciones y agregue adicionalmente un código para obtener el `idPaciente` del jQuery y actualicé la imagen de la consola al final.

Comment: Parece error de tecleo: `(isset($_POST['idPaciente'])) ? $_POST['idPacienteEliminar'] : '';` porque verificas si existe `idPaciente` y tratas de asignar `idPacienteEliminar`

Comment: Es cierto, sin embargo por lo que veo no se puede usar el mismo `idPaciente` para varias modales y que apunten a diferentes funciones de PHP, ya que este ultimo detalle que comentas se originó debido a que modifiqué `idPaciente` por `idPacienteEliminar` y olvidé modificar ese, al cambiar el nombre de la variable en la modal de eliminar funcionó sin problema alguno. Gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu preguntas por isset() ella solo verificara si la función existe en el espacio de PHP donde esta corriendo este script, por tanto si existe lo que no puede determinar es su valor ahí es cuando usas una segunda comparación.
En lugar de

```
if(isset($_POST['eliminarPaciente']))
```

Lo usas así

```
if (isset($_POST['eliminarPaciente']) && $_POST['eliminarPaciente'] == '1')
```

Donde '1' en la segunda comparación seria el value="1" que tendrías que ponerle en el código HTML a tu elemento checkbox, así el checkbox tendría valor no vacío y seria '1'